# Use Excel-VBA (MSXML2.XMLHTTP object) to update SharePoint List

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list, msxml6

**General Info.**: I need to update (add/edit) a SharePoint list from Excel. I was able to do it with a `ListObject`, however this is not the direction we are leading to.

After reading through all Google possibilities, I came up (maybe I'm wrong) with the idea to use `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` object to update the SharePoint List.

**Current Problem**: My code below runs through untill the end, I get `objXMLHTTP.Status = 200`, but the SharePoint List is not updated.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Const SharepointUrl As String = "http://share.corning.com/sites/ipp/PMOSandbox/"
Const ListName As String = "{60CE6622-D25B-447A-BFBF-8F3DD5B9FCF0}"
Const VIEWNAME As String = "{91ADBAE5-479F-4C80-A5FF-8EDA7A233B82}"

Sub Add_Item()

Dim objXMLHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP    
Dim strListNameOrGuid As String
Dim strBatchXml As String
Dim strSoapBody As String    
Dim ValueVar As String, FieldNameVar As String

Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

FieldNameVar = "IPP #"
ValueVar = "Shai"

'Add New Item'    
strBatchXml = "<Batch OnError='Continue'><Method ID='1' Cmd='New'><Field Name='" + FieldNameVar + "'>1004</Field>" + _
          "<Field Name='Title'>Uploaded from VBA</Field>" + _
          "<Field Name='Next KD Status'>" + ValueVar + "</Field>" + _
          "</Method></Batch>"

objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", SharepointUrl + "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx", False
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems"

strSoapBody = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' " _
 & "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' " _
 & "xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><UpdateListItems " _
 & "xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>" & ListName _
 & "</listName><updates>" & strBatchXml & "</updates></UpdateListItems></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

objXMLHTTP.send strSoapBody

Do
    ' wait for response
Loop Until objXMLHTTP.Status = 200

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

MsgBox "Finished Running !"

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps using ADO would be a better option? You can just update the table with a SQL statement.

Comment: @RyanWildry I'm quite open to suggestions, how do you implement it ?

Comment: Connect with ADO, see: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/ the Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0 portion then update the table with a connection string. It looks like you already have the list GUID, you'll need that to setup the connection.

Comment: @RyanWildry Thanks , but I've already read that page, it doesn't provide information how to access a specific record and modify a certain field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic outline of how to do this with ADO.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Update()
On Error GoTo ErrHand

    'Create the connection object with ADO
    Dim conn        As Object: Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    'Write your update statement
    Dim sql         As String
    sql = "Update MyTable set Field1= 'A', Field2='B' Where MyID=1234"

    'Open the connection and submit the update
    'In my experience, credentials should be requested by the server -
    'by way of a windows pop-up
    With conn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
                            "DATABASE=MySharePointURL;" & _
                            "LIST={MyListGUID};"
        .Open
        .Execute sql
    End With

CleanExit:
    If conn.State = 1 Then conn.Close: Set conn = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHand:
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
    GoTo CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the assistance, I'll test it tomorrow at work. How do you use a `sql` in this case to update 2 fields (let's say `"Next KD Status"` value from `"LA"` to `"GA"` , and `"Status"` from `"GR"` to `"YL`"), where the Field `"IPP#"` equals 1002

Comment: Sounds like a new SO SQL question. Perhaps try emulating your environment in Access/Excel to see what you need to do. It pretty much sounds like an update statement with some parameters in the where clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, now just braking my head around the SQL syntax for the update, are you good with SQL as well ? should I send you the link to my new post ?

Comment: Sure, I can take a look

Comment: I should mention this is a basic example. You should parameterize these queries. See the SO documentation on ADO, it does a fantastic job: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3578/working-with-ado#t=201703071432481096399

Comment: Thanks for the added info, I got it to work, but I haven't started yet handling all the errors handling, what you've sent will help me :)